# Linker command failed for custom framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, xcode4.5, clang

I am creating a framework using XCode4.5.

I have created an 'Aggregate Target' too. Now when I use the framework in my test app, I get the following error:

```
ldframework not found MyFramework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please suggest what could I be missing...

[image]

Comment: Have you linked your custom framework in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section under "Build Phases"?

Comment: Yes Popeye.. I am doing it already..

Comment: Well that little bit of information should have been in the original post.

Comment: That image tells us **nothing** as we can't even read it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build phases , and "Link binary" , click on + sign , and then add "MyFramework"